# Suggest how to do this matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix

Have a look at the *Mathematica* calculation

```
z = {{1}, {0}};

o = {{0}, {1}};

Ψ = Sin[θ]*KroneckerProduct[z, z, z] + 
Cos[θ]*KroneckerProduct[o, o, o] // MatrixForm

Ψt = 
Transpose[{{Sin[θ]}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {0}, {Cos[θ]}}] // MatrixForm

ρ = Ψ.Ψt;

ρ // MatrixForm
```

After calculation at the last step we shall get a $6\times 6$ matrix ρ. But *Mathematica* is showing me 
$$\begin{bmatrix}\sin[\theta] \\ 0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\ \cos[\theta]\end{bmatrix} . \begin{bmatrix} \sin[\theta] & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& \cos[\theta]\end{bmatrix}$$

I like to get the in matrix form for farther calculations. Might be I have done some mistake, that I do not know. What changes to do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! In case you didn't know, you can format your code better by putting four spaces at the front of every code block (or click on the curly-brace button above the question editing area). Further, wrap short inline code snippets in a pair of backticks ``. This will make your post easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is you're assigning the matrix form to your variable.  Put matrix form on after setting your variable, e.g. `MatrixForm[p = mat]` not `p = mat // MatrixForm`.

```
z = {{1}, {0}};
o = {{0}, {1}};
MatrixForm[
 p = Sin[t]*KroneckerProduct[z, z, z] + 
   Cos[t]*KroneckerProduct[o, o, o]]
MatrixForm[pt = Transpose[p]]
r = p.pt;
r // MatrixForm
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are comfortable with the Kronecker product, you might also be interested in the command `Outer` which can be used quite succinctly in this setting:

```
z = {1, 0};
o = {0, 1};
p = Flatten[Sin[t]*KroneckerProduct[z, z, z] +  Cos[t]*KroneckerProduct[o, o, o]];
mat = Outer[Times, p, p];
MatrixForm[mat]
```

which gives the desired form.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer gave me something new to learn.